# Auto redirect 127.0.0.1:8000 to 127.0.0.1:8000/app/

Tags: xampp, localhost

When I run the server, instead of the `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, I'm redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/`.

I even uninstalled and reinstalled my Xampp and Composer and also when i turn `off` or `on` my Xampp, I don't see any difference and this automatic redirect happens :(

Comment: have you checked the apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf ?

Comment: Did you modify any .htacess files?